# Rails Format date before save where date and format both are given in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, date-formatting, strftime

There are 2 parameters like **t_date** and **date_format** on create record request.
eg. t_date = "2021-05-15" and date_format="yyyy-mm-dd"

**NOTE**: date_format can be different in different requests.

I want to save date in t_date field as per format given in date_format field.

how can I write below create query for above problem?

obj = Object.create(t_date: ?)

Trying to save record with date value as per given format in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

while saving dates, and times and datetime objects we need to save directly(like all other fields). we need not to menction the format in which it needs to be saved while saving to database. in views we need to use some view helpers . if we use those view helper by passing format as argument to those view helper methods. it will display as per our menctioned format.

There are some datatimes methods like for example below.

```
User.created_at.strftime("pass the format here")
```

its vary bad idea to save format of the date or time. in case if user want the option to select the date or time or datetime as per his format then, add a column to user table like format and while displaying the dates and times fetch the user selected format and pass this as argument to the view helper methods. saving format for every request to database is a very bad database design.

Times also we should not save the times by converting into various time zones. we should save the times as it is(by default it saves in UTC time) while displaying the times from database we need to display in what ever the timezone he is in. you should maintain a column like `timezone` to save the users timezone and while displaying you need to pass this timezone as argument to view helper methods